# Using extern and linking files

Tags: c++

So I am supposed to link these 3 files but when I run use.cpp and it tells me there is a problem with print_foo and print so there must be a problem with my linking or declarations;(FYI I am using Xcode to compile)

This is the header file

```
// my.h   (HEADER FILE)
extern int foo;
void print_foo();
void print(int);
```

This is my.cpp

```
// my.cpp
#include "my.h"
#include "std_lib_facilities_5.h"

void print_foo() {
    cout << foo;
}

void print(int i) {
    cout << i;

}

int main() {

    return 0;
}
```

And this is use.cpp

```
// use.cpp
#include "my.h"   /* Declaration made available here */

int foo;

int main() {

     foo = 7;
     print_foo();
     print(99);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Prefer not to use global variables.

Comment: its part of the homework lo

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention how you are compiling them, on unix like systems you can do

`$ gcc my.cpp use.cpp -o my`

to compile

Answer (score 1):

You must delete the main in

> my.cpp

You can't have two main.